Enabling "/server-status" (mod-status) in ddev project
How to enable /server-status endpoint (apache mod-status)?
By default, mod-status is enabled in ddev projects. But if I want to use it I need to change module config file /etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf to this:
 <IfModule mod_status.c>
        <Location /server-status>
                SetHandler server-status
                Require all granted
        </Location>

        ExtendedStatus On

        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyStatus On
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>

And this doesn't work for me. If it even does, it will be replaced to default config after ddev project restart.
Is there an easy way to do it?

The #ddev-generated line in any DDEV config must be removed in order to prevent DDEV from replacing it. It's the signal that DDEV "owns" the file. When you experiment with this in .ddev/apache/apache-site.conf, remove the #ddev-generated.
